# show desktop view for mobile view

Tags: html, css, web

please tell me how can I set full of desktop view for my my mobile view
I tried this tag but it was not useful and in mobile view everything is a mess now:

```
meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0" /> 
meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
```

should I use JavaScript or other things?

Answer (score 1):

You should use CSS media queries for desktop/mobile sizes:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Comment: Tnx man can u send me a youtube video that teaches this tags?